# What is the path of PyCharm in ubuntu when installed from the software store?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, path

I installed PyCharm Professional from the Ubuntu Software Store. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 although I don't think that matters much here.

[image]

I can't use it in the command line. I can't happen to find where it's installed so that I can add the executable launcher to the path. It is working absolutely fine but I'm habituated to open apps from the command line so it would help if I could use something similar to `subl .` or `code .`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycharm is installed as a snap in Ubuntu 20.04. Typing `pycharm-professional` from the cli should launch it. Otherwise you can launch using the full path:

```
$(mount | grep pycharm | awk '{ print $3 }')/bin/pycharm.sh
```

On my system the full path is `/snap/pycharm-professional/198/bin/pycharm.sh`. Yours will be slightly different and so use the command above.

Answer (score 0):

one possible way to find is:

```
dpkg -l | grep app_name
```

If it's snap package, try:

```
snap find app_name
```